# Data Extensions from Data Filters. Some are quickly updated, some are very slow, but the setup is almost identical

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions

Hope you can help me.
I've set up a series of Data Filters to find the least engaged of my permissions. The Data Filters return permissions in Data Extensions.

But even though the Data Filters are set up almost identically, the time it takes to refresh the Data Extensions is very different.

When I update the group of least active permissions for Germany, the Data Extension is refreshed within 2 minutes. But when I update the group of least active permissions for Switzerland, it take approx. 90 minutes to refresh the Data Extension.

The Data Filter both uses a Data Extensions with all permissions across countries as source. This Data Extension has approx. 305.000 permission.
Approx. 100.000 of these are german, and approx. 8.000 are swiss.

The Data Filter preview for both are attached.

**Can I make any changes to make the swiss Data Filters update the Data Extensions as quickly as the german Data Filter**

Thank you :)

[image: Data Filter Germany]

[image: Data Filter Switzerland]

Comment: I am guessing this is something to do with the order they are run in, or something with the 'backend' of SFMC.  I would recommend putting in a ticket to support and have them take a deep dive into the issue. They will have access to information we can only guess at.

Answer (score 0):

Performance on Data Filters can be slow in returning results, and recommendation if you want the most optimal performance would be to use SQL (or Audience Builder if purchased)

Filter performance can be affected if you are running multiple filters at the same time. Also if there's date logic for the filter to work through.

Raising a ticket may help explain specifically why your filter isn't returning results more optimally, but my recommendation would be to use SQL if you can